# Assign OberservableCollection to ListBox and exclude some entries

Tags: c#, listbox, observablecollection, inheritance

I have different classes inherited from one Interface, all of them are added into a OberservableCollection. Could someone explain me how to assign all values of Observablecollection to my Listbox, except of class b.

Suppose (edit):

```
private void start()
{
    DP = new MyClass();
    this.ListBox.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<WInstance>(MyClass.Handler.Instances.OfType<WInstance>());
}

...
class Handler() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<HandlerItem> Instances { get; private set; } 
 ...
}

class HandlerItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Instance inst { get; private set; } //Instance could be WInstance or CInstance
}
```

During runtime MyClass receive from remote-Computer some objects of WInstance or CInstance. if i try to solve it with Instances.OfType() it seems that my ItemsSource wount be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = new List<Instance>();

//.. add all items to your list here.


ObservableCollection<Instance> OCI = new ObservableCollection<Instance>(list.OfType<classa>());
// the above will generate a new ObservableCollection which contains all items of type classa from list.
```

Comment: first of all thank you. my observablecollection gain some entries dynamicly, so i have to implement a Workaround to get the current values, isnt it?

Comment: @ViktorZimmermann I don't understand what you mean by "gain some entries dynamically". Please post your code. Still, my solution should work.